# Pentaho - Dash Board Designing

Tags: jsp, pentaho, dashboard, dashboard-designer

I am using pentaho report designer 3.9GA,

now I have to create a dash board using pentaho, I have googled a lot and cant find a single valid link on creating a dashboard using pentaho report designer.

1. can we create a dashboard using pentaho report designer?
2. If yes means anybody provide a link/tutorial for creating a sample dashboard.

or

- what else can i use to create a pentaho dash board and also after creating the dashboard can i deploy it to my Pentaho BI server 4.5.
- also i need to know about any other free and good dashboard designers
  (I am preferring pentaho community editions).

My dash board's main page will look like the below, and need to drill down on clicking the date (will extract data from my MySQL DB).

[image: Main Page of DashBoard]

Answer (score 2):

Pentaho reporting cannot be used for creating dashboards - however you can embed pentaho reports within a dashboard if you want to.

You need to look at the "Ctools" from webdetails. Start with the ctools-installer script then take a look at the CDE product. This is an very complete dashboarding framework. There is documentation on the ctools websites, and if you get really stuck you can buy some very cheap tutorials which are pretty good. ( There are tutorials available from webdetails or ambientbi - take your pick!  Both are based on CDE )

Webdetails are the main developer of CDF which is the dashboard framework that Pentaho themselves use for their EE products - so its a good product!

Comment: Hi codek, thanks for ur cmt. I need to know one more thing too.
  do pentaho have their own dashboard designer?

Comment: yes they do, but it's in the enterprise version only, and only for end users, so is not very advanced. CDE is aimed more at the BI developer.  Just to be clear, the underlying framework for both is the same - CDF.

Comment: Hi codek i have tried installing ctools, and added the issues faced
- i will Appreciate any help

Comment: Oh, I see, edit the ctools-installer.sh file and put set -x at the top. This will give you debug output. I suspect you need to install wget as part of cygwin, which the ctools script uses.

Comment: I have installed both wget and unzip pkgs, still i got the pbm...
so i created a separate linux environment and installed it.. now working fine

Comment: as for next step, 
1.I need to know is there any documentation or tutorial for creating a drillable dashboard using CDE.
i have found this good simple tutorial,
[link](http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2011/06/creating-dashboards-with-cde/)
but its not abt creating a drillable dashboard.

Comment: just take a look at the clickAction on the various components, you can access the value clicked upon ( series / value etc ) and then pass it on to the next dashboard.  Google for "passing parameters between dashboards" or something and you'll find examples in the pentaho forum about how to read it back in.

Answer (score 0):

In the CDE dashboard,you can use prpt execute to implement the chart which create on pentaho report designer

Answer (score 0):

You asked for a tutorial - here is a tutorial on Pentaho Community Edition Dashboard Editor. It is fairly basic but will show you how to do what you are looking to do:  http://holowczak.com/getting-started-with-pentaho-community-edition-dashboard-editor-cde/